# How to detect "device mode" (MVC3 + Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with MVC3 and Bootstrap Responsive, and I want to detect by Razor (or javascript) which mode is active (desktop, tablet or phone) to show the correct partial view in one case or another.

For example:

```
@if( mode=='phone')
{
    @html.Partial("_partialPhone")
}
@if( mode=='desktop')
{
    @html.Partial("_partialDesktop")
}
...etc
```

I don't want to use just  ".visible-phone" "visible-tablet" and ".visible-desktop" css classes, because although only one partial view is displayed, all of them are loaded in the DOM and rendered by Razor engine. And that is not good for a Phone and Tablet performance.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do that with MVC4 (I don't know if this functionality exists in MVC3, but the sample on the site below uses MVC4 so that's what I'm basing my response on).

[Switchable Mobile Views](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreateAGreatMobileExperienceForYourWebsiteTodayPlease.aspx)

It appears that you can start making files named like [ActionName].Mobile.cshtml and ASP.NET automatically uses those when it detects a request from a mobile device (and this appears to be customizable so you could create your own for tablets or whatever). He demonstrates something similar to what you are asking about in Razor - he renders different links based on the current display mode, but I assume this would work to render different partial views as well:

```
@if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice && Request.HttpMethod == "GET")
{
    <div class="view-switcher ui-bar-a">
        @if (ViewContext.HttpContext.GetOverriddenBrowser().IsMobileDevice)
        {
            @: Displaying mobile view
            @Html.ActionLink("Desktop view", "SwitchView", "ViewSwitcher", new { mobile = false, returnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery }, new { rel = "external" })
        }
        else
        {
            @: Displaying desktop view
            @Html.ActionLink("Mobile view", "SwitchView", "ViewSwitcher", new { mobile = true, returnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery }, new { rel = "external" })
        }
    </div>
}
```

Though if you have separate mobile views and desktop views then it I wouldn't think you'd need to manually switch between the two partials like you are asking about.

[Related information](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakingASwitchableDesktopAndMobileSiteWithASPNETMVC4AndJQueryMobile.aspx)

Comment: Thnks... @Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice exist in MVC3, but doesn't work properly. returns "false" for new devices...

Comment: @Gonzalo Try configuring new browser agents here: `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[version number]\CONFIG\Browsers`

Answer (score 3):

Media queries happen on the *client*.
This is fundamentally impossible.

You could have the client set its size in a cookie, then read the cookie on the server.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, it doesn't have to be a cookie? Could be a GET param/similar after the initial page loads?

Comment: yes, but maybe I can detect it by javascript and load the partialview by Ajax